# How i can write url address into javascript library in Resource/Public in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

> I am creating a library and i need to use url links into it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to use this bundle:

http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle